# Retrieve empty array or null in mongoDB documents

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection with all the students of my school. Each document has a `sports` array property that lists the sports practiced by each student, but that property may appear either as `sports: []` or `sports: null` or not appear at all.

How can I retrieve all the documents that fall in one of the aforementioned three cases?

How can I add a sport to a student which only has one sport but not expressed as array, i.e. a student that has `sports: "Badminton"`? Can this property become an array?

Answer (score 14):

You can use the [`$in`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator to query for docs where a field's value is any of a list of target values:

```
db.students.find({sports: {$in: [null, []]}})
```

Note that the `null` case also matches docs where the field isn't present.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use $elemMatch for this:

```
db.students.find({ $not: { $elemMatch: { $exists: true } } })
```

This tells mongoDB to fail if the array exists and has values. It only returns values that are null or empty.

Answer (score 0):

On supported (later) versions on MongoDB:

```
find({field:{$not:{$size: 0}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

**In mongoDb filter query:**

```
1. {field: {$size: 0}} // When find field array size is 0.
2. {field: {$not {$size: 0}}} // When find field array size is not empty.
3. {field: {$in: [null, []]}} // When field array null or empty.
```