# How to return all documents in mongodb that have an empty Array field

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

How to return all documents in mongodb that have an empty Array field. I want to get all the documents that have the categories.length=0

below my code not working:

```
  @Aggregation(pipeline = {
        "{ '$match': { 'categories.length' : 0}}"
      })
    List<CategoryProduct> findwihtoutCategory();
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve empty array or null in mongoDB documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101017/retrieve-empty-array-or-null-in-mongodb-documents)

Comment: perfect..thanks it works: "{ '$match': { 'categories' : {$in: [null, []]}}}"